# Dynamodb design recommendation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Use Case : Company X and Company Y publishes product information . For ex Company X publishes product information like Product X, Product Y and Company Y publishes product information Z and K.

Consumer likes Product X from Company X and Product Z from Company K. Based on consumer liking, we need to start displaying products that are published by Company X and Y. When the customer navigates to a specific screen in mobile app they should see all products they liked. In my use case, the consumer should see Product X and Product Z.

Question :
For DynamoDB design, Would you recommend saving the products liked by customers in one table and published products from Company x and Company Y in another table. Then programmatically retrieve the records from two tables and filter only the records liked by customer and display them ?

Is the above correct or do you have any other DB design recommendation for the above use case?

**Edits : Updated Use Case**

Retailer X publishes advertisement information for two products.
For ex :  Product X1 with the offer : Buy 2 get one free and this advertisement lasts for 5 days starting 03/23/2019 till 03/28/2019

Product X2 with the offer : Buy 2 get one free and this advertisement lasts for 5 days starting 03/23/2019 till 04/01/2019

Consumer A has earlier subscribed or liked the product X1 from Retailer X Advanced on 03/15/2019. Effective 03/23 Consumer A must see the advertisement information (Product X1 : Buy 2 get one free)  published by retailer X until 03/28.

Consumer B has subscribed or liked the Product X2 from Retailer X on 03/25/2019. Effective 03/25/209 Consumer B must see the advertisement information (Product X1 with the offer : Buy 2 get one free) published by retailer X until 04/01.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should look into the preview of [Amazon Personalize](https://aws.amazon.com/personalize/). It's built for the use-case you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Below is one approach you can take

```
| pk    |   sk                     |   GSI1
| user1 |   Likes#CompX#ProdA      |  CompX#ProdA |DateOfLiking:123 | ... some other ProductMetadata
| user1 |   Likes#CompY#ProdC      |  CompY#ProdC |DateOfLiking:123 | ... some other ProductMetadata
| compX |   Products#ProdA         |              | price:12        | ... some other metadata
| compX |   Products#ProdB         |              | price:14        | ... some other metadata
| compY |   Products#ProdC         |              | price:15        | ... some other metadata
| compY |   Products#ProdD         |              | price:19        | ... some other metadata

pk is sk of GSI1
```

For Finding all the product from company X you can do

```
Select * where pk=compC and sk startswith Products
```

For finding all the likes by user1 you can do

```
Select * where pk=user1 and sk startswith Likes
```

---

bonus use case(and left for further thinking)

For finding who all liked a product

```
 Select * from GSI1 where pk=CompX#ProdA
```

Comment: Thanks @best wishes but the requirement is to display the products that user liked only if they are published by company for a specific date range . For example company x can say schedule to publish a product from 04/01/2019 to 04/05/2019. The users should see the product that they liked from company only from 04/01 till 04/05 . You can think of this scenario as a retailer publishing advertisements for a product that is valid for a date range and user who liked the product from retailer should see the advertisements only for the date range .

Comment: you can change sk to have date as well like `Likes#1234321#CompX#ProdA` where  1234321 is last date of publish. and change you query appropriately.

Comment: I have updated the use case to make sure my question is clear. I still see challenges fulfilling the use case with single table as retailers could publish the information anytime and consumers could like the information anytime. Can you provide an updated design approach?

Comment: yes the updated use case can be solved by ```Select * where pk=user1 and sk greaterthan Likes#1234566``` where 1234566 is current epoch time, by doing this the expired/stale offers wont be visible.

Comment: when the retailer updates the information all the liked entities needs to be updated.

Comment: When you say all the liked entities needs to be updated . What do they need to be updated with ?

Comment: since offer ending date is there in our key, whenever product owner changes offer ending date we will need to update all the entities where that offer is liked

Comment: Thanks @best wishes Is there a way to more this to a chat conversation? Sorry have few more questions. Thanks so far for helping with this question. Want to make sure the dynamodb design is done properly.